# WooCommerce import, products show up in backend not in frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For a client of mine I refactored some code that didn't work anymore. The script imports (variable) products from a CSV. That all works fine, the products and the attributes get imported and show up all complete in the backend.

The weird thing is, the products don't show up on the front-end of the website. That is, untill we save it just once from the backend (really, just pressing the save button for that product without doing anything else).

During the refactoring we found this code;

```
  $test = new WC_Product($id);
  $test->variable_product_sync();
  $test = null;
```

This doesn't work anymore with the new WooCommerce, everything is static now. How can we implement this function now? And we are not sure this solves is though.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found it. You can dro the variable_product_sync. Make sure you set the meta _visible to 'visible' trough update_post_meta.

Answer (score 0):

```
include_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php' );

$product_variable = new WC_Product_Variable($product_id);
$product_variable->sync($product_id);
wc_delete_product_transients($product_id);
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, could you explain your answer?